# How to make gulp.js work on a Ubuntu Trusty vagrant box (error caused by xdg-open)

Tags: ubuntu, gulp, vagrant, gulp-browser-sync

#### Background

I have a gulp.js build system written by another developer; as for myself, I have absolutely no background with gulp. In order to avoid cluttering my system with gulp, I tried to install and run gulp in a Vagrant VM (Ubuntu Trusty 64). Gulp seems to have installed correctly.

#### The Issue

When running `gulp`, tasks are run, then the access infos are printed:

```
 ----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:9000
    External: http://10.0.2.15:9000
 ----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://10.0.2.15:3001
 ----------------------------------
[Frontend_Devil] Serving files from:
```

Followed by the error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /path/to/node_modules/opn/xdg-open ENOENT
  at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
  at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
  at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

A friend of mine is running this on Windows and does not encounter the problem. Does anybody have an idea about where to start solving this problem?

#### What I've tried

Apart from some fruitless research on the search engines, I've commented any lines in the Gulpfile related to `browserSync`, which prevents the error from being thrown, but also removes all the webserver/reload functionality.